# Configure xdebug on portable drive

Tags: xdebug

I am trying to set xdebug. I do use XAMPP portable, PHP v 7.4.11. I downloaded dlls `php_xdebug-3.0.2-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll` and `php_xdebug-3.0.2-7.4-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll` and put them in `\xampp\php\ext`. Then I set `php.ini` file:

```
implicit_flush = On

zend_extension_ts = H:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.2-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0 
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = \tmp 
xdebug.dump_globals=On 
xdebug.show_exception_trace=On 
xdebug.collect_params=4
```

I restarted server, but I can not see any info about xdebug at `http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php` or among modules in php shell. I have tried both downloaded dlls, various ports, relative/absolute path. Nothing works. There are a few tutorials online, but they might be out of date, or is there problem with portable setting? Any idea, please?

Comment: Cannot say anything about "portable" part .. but: 1) You are using Xdebug v3 ... but keep using v2 param names. They do almost NOTHING in v3. Please check https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide 2) `\tmp` -- that's an invalid path on Windows... In any case: 3) `phpinfo()` should report that Xdebug is there. If you do not see it -- then you do something wrong. 4) https://learnxdebug.com/ 5) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw

Comment: Thanks about v2 params point. `\tmp` is xampp folder, this could work

Answer (score 0):

I changed dll`s path and settings:

```
zend_extension=php_xdebug-3.0.2-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll

[XDebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host = localhost
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.output_dir = H:\xampp\tmp
```

Now after `php -v` in php console I get:

```
PHP 7.4.11 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2020 13:18:06) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v3.0.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

So that is good. At `http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php`:
[image: phpinfo screenshot]

According to https://wiki.php.net/internals/extensions, since php 5.5 there is no needed to fill whole path to dll, only it`s name

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` output -- what config file(s) are used. You may have different files for CLI and web server (quite typical case these days on Linux and Mac)

Comment: I changed settings again (see my answer) and restarted whole PC, not only server, now is all right. I will try relative paths later. Changed ini file was correct