# Xdebug is not installed on XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

I want to install Xdebug so because my PHP version is `7.4.8`, I downloaded `php_xdebug-3.0.2-7.4-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll` file and placed it at `php\ext\` folder.

Then I opened up `php.ini` and added these lines at the end of it:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="F:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.2-7.4-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=15
```

After that I restarted Apache and opened up dashboard but the Xdebug is not showing there, meaning that it is not installed yet somehow.

So what should I do now, in order to install it properly?

Comment: 1) You are using Xdebug v3 ... but keep using v2 param names. They do almost NOTHING in v3. Please check https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide 2) Check `phpinfo()` output -- it will show if Xdebug is installed or not. 3) Try extension name only instead of the full path. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66220436/783119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using an older version of XDebug that is verified to work in the XAMPP Dashboard:
https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.9.7-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll

If that does not work, then there might be more details on this page that could help:
https://gist.github.com/odan/1abe76d373a9cbb15bed

Answer (score 0):

Only helped me string

```
xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD
```

all

```
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.discover_client_host = false
xdebug.client_host="localhost"
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD
```